# Android- How do I standardize the coordinate location a user has tapped on different sized screens?

Tags: android, screen

I'm trying to build an app for the analysis of peaks, but I am having trouble with the idea of a user selecting peaks on a screen image.

I understand the .getX() and .getY() methods work to return the coordinates of a user's touch, but how do I compensate for differently sized screens?

The idea is to have the coordinates translated into an internal ruler, which then returns the peak data. I realized that by using absolute coordinates for the internal ruler, I am making my app accurate only for my own device.

i.e. a touch on (15,15) would not be on the same location on a G3 vs a Galaxy, correct?

In short, is there a way to keep relative coordinate positions?

Thanks

EDIT: Relative to the user's device screen size

Comment: post amended. Thanks

Comment: so whats wrong in  `ev.getX() / (float)  view.getWidth()`?

Comment: Wow. I feel pretty stupid now. Thanks for the input!